# Given a positive integer $n$, find all $x$ and $y$ such that $\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}} =\dfrac1{\sqrt{x}}+\dfrac1{\sqrt{y}} $ with $1 \le x \le y$.

Tags: diophantine-equations, radicals

This is based
on an earlier question here.

Given a positive integer $n$,
is this method for
finding all positive integers
$x$ and $y$
with $x \le y$
such that

$\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}
=\dfrac1{\sqrt{x}}+\dfrac1{\sqrt{y}}
$

correct?

All variables here are
positive integers,

My solution:

For each representation
$n=ku^2v^2
$
with $(u, v)=1, u \le v
$
we have
$x=u^2z,
y=v^2z,
$
with
$z=k(u+v)^2
$.

Check:

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{\sqrt{x}}+\dfrac1{\sqrt{y}}
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{u^2z}}+\dfrac1{\sqrt{v^2z}}\\
&=\dfrac1{u\sqrt{z}}+\dfrac1{v\sqrt{z}}\\
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{z}}\left(\dfrac1{u}+\dfrac1{v}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{k(u+v)^2}}\left(\dfrac{u+v}{uv}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{k}uv}\\
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{ku^2v^2}}\\
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}\\
\end{array}
$

My derivation.

$\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}
=\dfrac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{xy}}
$.

$\sqrt{n}
=\dfrac{\sqrt{xy}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}
$.

$\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})
=\sqrt{xy}
$

Squaring,

$n(x+y+2\sqrt{xy})
=xy
$
so
$\sqrt{xy}
=\dfrac{xy-n(x+y)}{2n}
$.

Therefore $xy$
is a square
since the square root of an integer
is rational if and only if
the integer is the square of an integer.

If $(x, y)=z$,
we must have
$x=u^2z, y=v^2z$
with
$(u, v)=1, u\le v$.

So
$n(u^2z+v^2z+2uvz)
=u^2v^2z^2
$
or
$n(u^2+v^2+2uv)
=u^2v^2z
$
or
$n(u+v)^2
=u^2v^2z
$.

Since
$(u, v)=1$,
$(uv, u+v)=1$
so that,
for some $k$,
$z=k(u+v)^2
$
so
$n
=ku^2v^2
$.

A solution is always
$k=n, u=v=1,
z=4n, x=4n, y=4n$.

The example that
inspired this:

If $n=20=2^25$,
$(k, u, v)
= (20, 1, 1),
(5, 1, 2)
$.
For the latter,
$z=5(1+2)^2=45,
x=45, y=4\cdot 45=180
$.

Another example:

If $n=100=2^25^2
$
then
$(k, u, v)
=(100, 1, 1),
(25, 1, 2),
(4, 1, 5),
(1, 2, 5)
$
for which,
respectively,
$(z, x, y)
=(400, 400, 400),
(225, 225, 900),
(144, 144, 3600),
(49, 196, 1225)
$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, was the "earlier question" you're referring to [$1/\sqrt x + 1/\sqrt y = 1/\sqrt{ 20}$ Find all pairs of positive integers](/q/4674152) (with this having a duplicate at [Positive integers satisfying $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{20}}$](/q/1859494))?

Comment: @martycohen How do you justify that $n$ must be of the form $ku^2 v^2$? What if there is a solution with square-free $n$ or $n = ku^2$ where $k$ is square-free?

Comment: @Nilotpal Sinha : For every positive integer $n$, there are positive integers $k,u,v$ satisfying $n=ku^2v^2,(u,v)=1$ and $u\leqslant v$. For $n=15=3\times 5$ which is square-free, $(k,u,v)=(15,1,1)$. For $n=12=3\times 2^2$ where $3$ is square-free, $(k,u,v)=(12,1,1),(3,1,2)$.

Comment: Your method looks correct. For $n=100$, you forgot to add $(k,u,v)=(1,1,10)$.

Comment: @NilotpalSinha - the justification starts with the line "My derivation". Before that is a proof that such representions work. After is the justficiation that anything that works has such a representation.

Answer (score 0):

We begin by rearranging terms to remove the surds from the divisors.
\begin{align}
\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{x}}+\dfrac1{\sqrt{y}}
\quad 1\le x\le y\tag{1}\\
\sqrt{xy}&=\sqrt{nx}+\sqrt{ny}\tag{2}\\
xy&=n (x + 2\sqrt{x y} + y)\tag{3}\\
\dfrac{xy}{n}&=\big(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\big)^2\tag{4}\\
\end{align}

It is clear that $\,n|xy.\quad$ It is useful when $\,xy\,$ is a perfect square, when
$\,x\,$ or $\,y\,$ are squares themselves, when $\,y=4x,\,$ and when $\,x=y=4n.\quad$ A number of these solutions are shown below.
$$(n,x,y)\in \big\{(1,4,4),(2,8,8),(3,12,12),(4,9,36),(4,16,16),(5,20,20),(6,24,24),(7,28,28),(8,18,72),(8,32,32),(9,16,144),(9,36,36),(10,40,40),(11,44,44),(12,27,108),(12,48,48)
\cdots
(28,112,112),\cdots\big\}$$